# SQL/Access 2010 - Group by Name and filtering data

Tags: sql, ms-access, filter, group-by

I have the following table as an example in MS Access 2010. I need to filter the table so there is only one row for each Name.

The criteria is that the Date must be most recent BUT no later than today's date (6th April).

```
Name   Date        Team
John   04/04/2018  A
John   02/02/2018  B
James  10/10/2018  A
James  03/03/2018  C
Matt   08/09/2018  D
```

This is the result I'm looking to get.

```
Name   Date        Team
John   04/04/2018  A
James  03/03/2018  C
```

My problem has been trying to filter this data while grouping the Names.

Comment: Add (Matt,08/09/2018, A) to the sample data, and adjust the expected result accordingly.

Comment: Also add (John, 04/04/2018, D).

Comment: I've added Matt. They wouldn't appear in the results as they need a date prior to the current date so the results wouldn't change. A row would never have the same name and date so another row for john on 04/04/2018 in team D wouldn't be entered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below query. It uses a correlated subquery, and filters out rows who don't have the max date:

```
SELECT *
  FROM table1 t
 WHERE t.Date = (SELECT MAX(s.date)
                     FROM table1 s
                    WHERE t.Name = s.Name
                      AND s.Date <= Date())
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a subquery to get the first criteria met (all dates <= today, and then pick the max and group them after)

```
SELECT Student, Max(Date) AS MaxDate, First(Team) AS FirstOfTeam
FROM (SELECT tbl_name.Student, Date, Team
FROM tbl_name
where Date <= Date())

GROUP BY Student;
```

Assuming you want to group teams by the first - As you are after the most recent date it shouldn't matter, as im assuming you wont have the same date entry for a person on different teams.

If this is an incorrect assumption let me know!

If you wanted to get the team names sorted with DLookup you can try this

```
SELECT Student, Max(Date) AS MaxDate, First(TeamID) AS FirstOfTeam
FROM (SELECT tbl_name.Student, tbl_name.Date, DLookUp("[TEAM]","TBL_TEAM","TeamID='" & Team & "'") AS TeamID
FROM tbl_name
WHERE (((tbl_name.[Date])<=Date())))
GROUP BY Student;
```

Comment: thanks, dont have access to db right now, where is the typo?

Comment: `CURRENT_DATE()` should be `DATE()` and add `Team` to the `GROUP BY` and should be good to go.  Now OP should change the field names from Name and Date to something that isn't reserved.  **Edit...** won't be good to go, can't group on `Team` :)

Comment: just updated that, Im not sure what OP wants done with team, so i've just gone with "first" for now, can expand later if they provide some insight!

Comment: That seems to work however my Team column is from a lookup table in Access where it's bound to the Team ID {1,2,3,4} not Team name {A,B,C,D} so using first(Team) results in the a numerical value rather than name. Any idea how to alter this?

Comment: @WillacyMe I have "recreated" as best I can, and with "Team" in the table being a textbox, look up field, the query is still showing A/B/C/D in the query, not the numbers.

What is the query being used for the lookup field?

Comment: This is the expression I'm currently using:
SELECT Student, Max(Date) AS MaxDate, First(Team) AS FirstTeam

FROM (SELECT Student, Date, Team

FROM table1

Where Date <= Date())


Group By Student;

Comment: The query used for the lookup field is;
SELECT [tblTeam].[TeamID], [tblTeam].[Team] FROM tblTeam ORDER BY [TeamID] DESC;

Comment: Assuming [TeamID] = 1, where [Team] = A, do you need to be selecting the ID in the lookup field? Perhaps just have the query be: SELECT [tblTeam].[Team] FROM tblTeam ORDER BY [TeamID] DESC;

Comment: @WillacyMe alternatively, you could use Dlookup to get the ID of the team, change field names as needed of course. I have provided an example in my answer.

Comment: Thank for your help. I've had more success with the other answer that was posted but appreciate your guidance.